How to solve the code 1 indicating that the function ".vsc.browser" cannot be found?
Running an R script line by line in VSCode the way I have it set up outputs the expected plots. However, if I run the entire script, I get the following code1:
[Running] Rscript "c:\Users\me\Documents\R\Projects\this_file.R"
Error in .vsc.browser(httpgd::hgd_url(history = TRUE), viewer = FALSE) : 
  could not find function ".vsc.browser"
Calls: scatter3D -> initplist -> plot.new -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

How can I avoid this error message?
It is likely related to including in .Rprofile the following
options(vsc.plot = FALSE, vsc.use_httpgd = FALSE)
options(device = function(...) {
  httpgd::hgd(silent = TRUE)
  .vsc.browser(httpgd::hgd_url(history = TRUE), viewer = FALSE)
})

because it stops outputting an error by changing to
if (interactive() && Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "") {
  Sys.setenv(TERM_PROGRAM = "vscode")
  if ("httpgd" %in% .packages(all.available = TRUE)) {
    options(vsc.plot = FALSE)
    options(device = function(...) {
      httpgd::hgd(silent = TRUE)
      .vsc.browser(httpgd::hgd_url(history = FALSE), viewer = "Beside")
    })
  }
  source(file.path(Sys.getenv(if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") "USERPROFILE" else "HOME"), ".vscode-R", "init.R"))
}

as in here.
Unfortunately the plots are no longer sent to the browser.
